# Factorize expression $(4a+3)^2-a^4$

Tags: factoring

The question is to factorize $(4a+3)^2-a^4.$

The answer I ended up with was $(4a+3-a^2)(4a+3-a^2).$

I got this by difference of two squares $\cdots.$

I would like to know if this is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote $(4a+3-a^2)(4a+3-a^2)$, it should have been $(4a+3-a^2)(4a+3+a^2)$.

Furthermore, notice that: $(4a+3+a^2)=(a+3)(a+1)$.

Comment: Sorry I meant (4a+3-a^2)(4a+3+a^2)

Answer (score -1):

**SIMPLE**

The question was to factorize $(4a+3)^2-a^4.$

IF you use difference of two squares we will get

LET $4a+3$  be $X$ and $a^2$ be $Y$

the $X^2-Y^2$

WE GET

$(4a+3-a^2)(4a+3+a^2).$

***UNDERSTOOD***

Further each of the quadratic equation can be factorised

$(x-1)(x-3)(x-/7+2)(x+/7+2)$

SO THE FINAL AWSER IS HERE

Comment: This is incomplete!

Comment: No, not really incomplete: the original expression has been factored. Now, each quadratic factor can be further factored (or at least one of them in integers)...but that could be left to the OP to complete.

Comment: @DonAntonio But he claims in his answer that it is the correct answer. He, himself does not leave any choice for the OP. Neither does he say 'you can continue from here...' or anything like that. I don't know. Maybe, I misinterpreted him.

Comment: The op asked if his solution was correct or not.         I just showed him the pathway

Comment: But if u want the answer i am giving it

Comment: @superbjhon I think tatan has a point here: in this kind of questions, and in this one in particular, there is hardly *the* correct answer, and yours could be seen as a first, important step towards factoring. Yet there are other possibilities, as other questions show: factoring further the quadratic factor(s) .

Comment: Now anyone has any problems